# .NET 4.6 - monodevelop on linux

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, .net-4.6

I have mono installed from beta channel (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) - version 4.0.4

I can't compile Visual Studio 2015 project.

In project options under Build->General the Target framework is .NETFramework 4.6 (Not installed).

Compilation errors:
[image: CompilationErrors]
Project settings:
[image: ProjectSettings]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to downgrade to .NET 4.5 profile if you do want to target both .NET and Mono, or you help Mono out by filling the gaps between 4.5 and 4.6, or you simply wait till someone else helps out.

> Updated: This answer applied to the Mono release at that time. Latest
>   Mono release does support .NET Framework 4.6 and above, so you don't
>   need to downgrade any more.

Comment: So what does "[check] C# 6.0" here : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ mean? How do I make cross platform project using C# 6.0 features (eg. null propagation)?

Comment: @smokeing Some C# 6.0 language features do not require you to run the program on .NET Framework 4.6. You should use multi targeting to compile against .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: @isomorphismes in Visual Studio, at project options change target framework version to .NET Framework 4.5. In MonoDevelop in project options, change runtime to .NET 4.5.